# C# Linq: Select numeric columns that accepts null

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, dataset

I have strongly typed dataset. Now I want to do a select on a datatable with linq.

My problem is that this table have numeric columns that allows null-values. But if there are datarows that have in this columns no values, I don't know to make the Select- command.

This is my query:

```
var query = from tab1 in localDataSet.simpleTable
            select new {
               line = tab1.IsLineNull ? null : tab1.line,
               wait = tab1.IswaitNull() ? null : tab1.wait
            }
```

I can't set line = null if tab1.IsLineNull() returns true, because the datatype 'decimal' (and all other number valuetypes) can't be null. But what should I choose instead? I can't choose 0 either.

Comment: Why is there a method created `IsLineNull` when all number valuetypes cannot be null?

Comment: @TimSchmelter they actually can be null using 'int?' or 'double?' and so on. Also works for bool

Comment: Change your model to use nullable types. See here for details; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: I know that they can in general, but OP has mentioned that they cannot: _"because the datatype 'decimal' (and all other number valuetypes) can't be null."_ Edit: I thought that OP would know nullables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you don't know how to create a [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb.aspx):

```
var query = from tab1 in localDataSet.simpleTable
        select new {
           line = tab1.IsLineNull ?   new Nullable<decimal>(): tab1.line,
           wait = tab1.IswaitNull() ? new Nullable<decimal>(): tab1.wait
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the null in your ? : to the type of tab1.line and tab1.wait.

```
var query = from tab1 in localDataSet.simpleTable
            select new {
               line = tab1.IsLineNull ? (decimal?)null : tab1.line,
               wait = tab1.IswaitNull() ? (decimal?)null : tab1.wait
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

put a

```
(int?)
```

or

```
(decimal?)
```

before `null`, it casts the `null` into a nullable integer/decimal

Also, if yours methods:

```
IsLineNull
IswaitNull
```

simply control if fields are null, you can reduce the problem in:

```
var query = from tab1 in localDataSet.simpleTable
            select new {
               line = (int?)tab1.line,
               wait = (int?)tab1.wait
            }
```